# Fill object from dataset using grouping in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to load the data from `datatable` to objects using Linq. Below is my scenario. I have below table structure and data:

```html
seq name    id  class
1   Rajesh  101 B
1   kumar   102 B
1   sandeep 104 A
2   Myur    105 B
2   Bhuvan  106 C
3   Siraz   107 A
```

Below is my class structures

```
public class student
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string meritClass { get; set; }
}

public class stdGroup
{
    public int seqId{get;set;}
    public List<student> students;
}
```

As a final output I should get a `Student` constructed for each seq. `stdGroup` object should be created grouping by `seq` [three objects].

Example:

`stdGroup` object 1 would contain 3 student objects

`stdGroup` object 2 would contain 2 student objects

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Would be nice to see some of your code you tried.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski, Sorry for not posted the code which I have tried [I tried many ways and confused on selecting one to put it here]. I will double check the questions for its clarity, format and typos before posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need (assuming by DataTable you mean [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
List<stdGroup> stdGroups = myDataTable
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(a =>  a.Field<int>("Seq"), a => new student() { id = a.Field<string>("Id"), name = a.Field<string>("name"), meritClass = a.Field<string>("class") })
    .Select(a => new stdGroup() { seqId = a.Key, students = a.ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

To break it down, firstly, get the datatable rows into a state where we can use linq,

```
.AsEnumerable()
```

Now, do the groupings - selecting `seq` as the key for the group, and build a student object for every entry, which will get assigned to the corresponding group.

```
.GroupBy(a =>  a.Field<int>("Seq"), a => new student() { id = a.Field<string>("Id"), name = a.Field<string>("name"), meritClass = a.Field<string>("class") })
```

Now, for each group create the `stdGroup` object, and populate the `seq` property from our group keys, and take the content of each group, and assign that to the `students` property.

```
.Select(a => new stdGroup() { seqId = a.Key, students = a.ToList() })
```

Finally, and optionally, convert to a list instead of enumerable.

```
.ToList();
```

Comment: Its working and solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I understood how grouping works here, Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out my implementation:

```
public class dbStudent
{
    public int seq;
    public string name;
    public int id;
    public string meritClass;
}

public class student
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string meritClass { get; set; }
}

public class stdGroup
{
    public int seqId { get; set; }
    public List<student> students { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dbStudebts = new List<dbStudent>();
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { seq = 1, name = "Rajesh", id = 101, meritClass = "B" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { seq = 1, name = "kumar", id = 102, meritClass = "B" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { seq = 1, name = "sandeep", id = 104, meritClass = "A" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { seq = 2, name = "Myur", id = 105, meritClass = "B" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { seq = 2, name = "Bhuvan", id = 106, meritClass = "C" });
        dbStudebts.Add(new dbStudent { seq = 3, name = "Siraz", id = 107, meritClass = "A" });

        var result = (from o in dbStudebts
                      group o by new { o.seq } into grouped
                      select new stdGroup()
                      {
                          seqId = grouped.Key.seq,
                          students = grouped.Select(c => new student()
                          {
                              name = c.name,
                              id = c.id,
                              meritClass = c.meritClass
                          }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually I have the DataTable and I want to convert directly from it. Anyways I have tried your implementation also. Thanks once again.